# How to activate updated drivers in Hyper-V

Tags: drivers, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, nic, adaptec

I am working on getting a host setup using Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 but am running into some issues with drivers.  I have been able to add the drivers via pnputil. When I check to which which drivers are actually being used though, the new drivers are not the ones being listed.

Currently there is an Adaptec 3805 which is using the driver version 16119.  I have added the drivers for 17342 (to match the firmware) but after a restart it has not switched to the newer version.

I have also updated the NIC drivers for an Intel PRO/1000 based on the 82563 and 82573 using drivers from Intels website which were released about 10 days ago.

I think I have what I should need, but am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you typed "pnputil -a infname".

What you actually wanted was "pnputil -i -a infname".

Comment: +1 Unfortunately MS decided to complicate things by separating the "Add" and "Install" flags.

Comment: "pnputil -i -a *.inf" was what I used, and it seemed to be successful from the command line, but when I connect to it with a computer management console and look at the driver versions being used it still just reports the old ones.  Could it be because I imported all of them?

Comment: You may need to reboot if the drivers failed to unload.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, for some reason I didn't get updated on your comment.  I have tried rebooting it a few times, I figured it might not switch to the new drivers until it was taken down and brought back up again.  I'm wondering if maybe this hardware is just so old that it's not able to use the latest drivers.

Comment: Still haven't figured out why I can't get this to work, but that project has been put aside for now. Since this is a good answer I'm gonna mark it as accepted, even though I'm still having trouble, it's just me, hehe.

Comment: I've been able to make this work in other systems without any issue, so I'm guessing this hardware is just too obsolete to work with the new drivers despite supposedly being supported. Thanks for the help!